# Looking for battery for Honda Activa 2010 Model

Tags: battery

I want 2 buy battery for honda activa 2010 model (it is acidic water not dry one)
Which brand should I opt for exide, amaron or any other(amco etc)?
Can I use dry one instead of acidic water.